VBA Autofilter "Does not contain" with a variable
I want to use VBA autofilter in Excel to filter a worksheet so that it shows rows that DO NOT contain the number "9" in column D.  I can get it to work when I just enter "9" as the criteria, however, I want the criteria to be a variable, and I can't figure out how to do that.  I get an error message if I remove the quotes, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
  Dim last_row1 As Long
  last_row1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
  Dim filternumber As String
  filternumber = Month(Date)      
  Dim ws2 As Worksheet
  Set ws2 = Worksheets(2)
  ws2.Activate
 
  On Error Resume Next
    ws2.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

  ws2.Range("D1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>filternumber"
  
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws2.Range("D2:D" & last_row1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  
  On Error Resume Next
    ws2.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0


Try this: Criteria1:="<>" & filternumber

FYI last_row1 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row would be less likely to break your code if a different worksheet happens to be active when it runs.

It should be criteria:= "<>" & filternumber
